# In material-ui v5 How are you meant to override the styles of properties that don't exist in the themes components

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I am trying to style MuiDataTables and am currently using the adaptv4theme to do it like below

```
declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/overrides' {
  export interface ComponentNameToClassKey {
    MUIDataTable: any;
    MUIDataTableFilterList: any;
  }
}

export const theme = createMuiTheme(
  adaptV4Theme({
    overrides: {
      MUIDataTable: {
        paper: {
          boxShadow: 'none',
        },
        responsiveBase: {
          overflow: 'clip',
        },
      },
      MUIDataTableFilterList: {
        chip: {
          margin: '8px',
        },
      },
```

However adaptV4Theme is getting deprecated and do not know how to upgrade my code to the new convention as when I try

```
theme.components = {
  ...theme.components,
  MUIDataTable:{
     overrideStyles: {

     },
  },
```

I get the following error:
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'MUIDataTable' does not exist in type 'Components'.

How am I meant to move away from using adaptV4Theme?

Answer (score 6):

The following declaration works when transitioning from mui-v4 to mui-v5:

```
export const theme = createTheme({
    components: {           // <------ rename "overrides" to "components"
      MUIDataTable: {
        styleOverrides: {   // <------ put override property INSIDE component definition
          paper: {
            boxShadow: 'none',
          },
          responsiveBase: {
            overflow: 'clip',
          },
        },
      }.
    },
});
```

See: https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#global-style-overrides